# Making ogr2ogr generate different files for each geometry

Tags: geometry, ogr2ogr, geopackage

Let's say I have a GeoPackage file with 5000 lines. Each line with its own MULTIPOLYGON geometry. I know I can use spatial functions with it and generate a new file as the following:

```bsh
ogr2ogr -f GPKG -sql "select st_buffer(geom,5) from database"  bufferedOutput.gpkg input.gpkg
```

In this example, the file `bufferedOutput.gpkg` is the result of my query in a new file... However, instead of generating a single file, I'd like to generate a different files for each geometry, something like getting the `ogc_fid` of my table and creating output files like `1.gpkg`, `2.gpkg` and so on.

Is there any way of doing it with `ogr2ogr` in a single line of code or would the only way be first splitting my original file into multiple files and then creating a second new file with the query that I want to make?

Comment: You'd have to add a bit more code.  You would need to read the list of ids from the table, then loop through each id, running the ogr2ogr command and adding the id to the sql query in the where clause `"where id = %id% "`

Comment: You could use ogrinfo to get the id list from the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up writing a bash script for solving this problem as suggested in the comments. I'm not sure if that's the best way of solving the problem. But it's functional:

```bsh
INPUT_FILE='input.gpkg'
OUTPUT_FOLDER='outputFolder'

if ! [ -d "$OUTPUT_FOLDER" ]; then mkdir -p "$OUTPUT_FOLDER" ; fi

layerName="$(ogrinfo -al "$INPUT_FILE" | grep 'OGRFeature' | sed 's/[0-9]*$//g' | uniq | sed 's/^.*(//g' | sed 's/).*$//g' | tr '\n' ' ')"
list="$(ogrinfo -al "$INPUT_FILE" | grep 'ogc_fid' | vim -e -c ':normal ggdd' -c ':g/./normal df=x' '+%p' -escq! /dev/stdin)"

for id in $list; do
    ogr2ogr -f GPKG -sql "select st_buffer(geom,5) from $layerName where qc_id = '$id'"  "$OUTPUT_FOLDER/$id.gpkg" "$INPUT_FILE"
done
```

Besides using `ogr2ogr`, I've also used `Vim` in a pipe to filter the `ids` that I needed.